# Understanding fragment stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have a action bar (actionbarsherlock) with tab navigation and I have a couple of action items as well. One of my action items displays a ListFragment and here is how I call it:

```
    case R.id.menuitem_info:
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        SherlockListFragment aboutListFragment = new AboutListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        ft.replace(R.id.root, aboutListFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Commit the transaction
        ft.commit();
        return true;
```

My problem is that when I hit the back button, I get an IllegalArgumentException.  I'm not sure how to remove the fragment from the view and display the previous view?

Here is my home button code:

```
    case android.R.id.home:
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
        return true;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I did the following in case android.R.id.home:

```
    case android.R.id.home:
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return true;
```

I hope this help you, for me works like a charm